# How can I speed up these nested SQL queries

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

When I try these queries it runs pretty slow, since I have a lot of data, but I can't exclude any more from the top query because I need to see first if the second query results in a 0 total for `futureAmts` AND the `on_hand` in the first query

```
$inv = odbc_exec($live,"SELECT * FROM V1ICPR WHERE Account='".$account."'");
while (odbc_fetch_array($inv))
{
    $futureOrds = 0;
    $checkFuture = odbc_exec($live,"SELECT Order_num FROM V1OEMF WHERE Account = '".$account."' AND Status='Open' AND Ship_date > '".date("Ymd")."'");
    while(odbc_fetch_array($checkFuture))
    {
        $getFutureAmt = odbc_exec($live,"SELECT Amount FROM V1OEOO WHERE bol='".odbc_result($checkFuture,'Order_num')."' AND Prod_code='".odbc_result($inv,'Prod_code')."'");            
        while (odbc_fetch_array($getFutureAmt)){

            $futureOrds = $futureOrds + intval(odbc_result($getFutureAmt,'Amount'));

        }
    }
```

I tried an `Inner Join` but that query is failing to run altogether, is there a problem with my INNER JOIN query? is there a faster way to code this?

```
    /*
    $checkFuture = odbc_exec($live,"SELECT V1OEMF.Order_num, V1OEOO.Amount FROM V1OEMF INNER JOIN V1OEOO ON V1OEMF.Order_num = V1OEOO.bol WHERE V1OEMF.Account = '".$account."' AND V1OEMF.Status='Open' AND V1OEMF.Ship_date > '".date("Ymd")."' AND V1OEOO.Prod_code='".odbc_result($inv,'Prod_code')."'")
    while(odbc_fetch_array($checkFuture))
    {
        $futureOrds = $futureOrds + intval(odbc_result($checkFuture,'Amount'));
    }
    */
```

If I run just one level the first one that just gets the product info, and no infor about future orders, it runs in like 2 seconds, but with these nested queries it can take 30 - 60 + seconds

TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[V1ICPR](
[Account] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Prod_code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Prod_desc] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Whs] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[On_hand] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[On_ord] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[On_hold] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Amt_avail] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[V1OEMF](
[Order_num] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Account] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Warehouse] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Weight] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Load_stop] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Pick_num] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Carrier] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Carrier_desc] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[pay_type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EDI] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Ship_date] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Order_date] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Order_time] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Consignee] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Cases] [int] NOT NULL,
[Long_ship_date] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Delivery_date] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Long_del_date] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Long_edi_date] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Long_entry_date] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EDI_time] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Appt_num] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Cust_ord_num] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Cons_ord_num] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Ord_weight] [int] NOT NULL,
[Ord_cube] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Cube_lbs] [int] NOT NULL,
[Est_pallets] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Address_1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Address_2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Address_3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Address_4] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Prov] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Postal] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[V1OEOO](
[bol] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Account] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
[Prod_code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Lot_num] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Amount] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Prod_desc] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on each of the columns in your `WHERE` clauses? Please post the table structure for each of these tables.

Comment: Add indexes on each of those columns, and this whole thing will run dramatically faster.

Comment: Use `LIMIT 1` where you expect only 1 result. Big difference if you have it in the inner loop a lot

Comment: cool and @Ed Cottrell adding indexes won't require I drop and recreate tables or change any queries?

I will try that as well Martijn

Comment: No, you can use `ALTER TABLE`. Exact syntax depends on which database system you are using.

Comment: I am using MSSQL (TSQL) 

@Martijn is that like TOP 1 in MSSQL where it just gets the first result that matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This solution is already addressed in the comments, but I am adding it as an answer for the benefit of future readers.*

You need to add indexes on each of the columns in your `WHERE` clauses. This will dramatically increase the speed of each query if, as you say, you have a lot of data. You can do this with an `ALTER TABLE` command.

Also, use `TOP 1` (for MSSQL, `LIMIT 1` for MySQL) whenever you expect only one result, especially in the inner loops.